# How to get uname correct info with uname_hack

Tags: unix, solaris, uname

I need to get correct information from uname command when uname-hack script is running on Solaris.
More details about uname-hack:
https://blogs.oracle.com/jonh/entry/it_s_been_a_long
There is any file that contain this information or any command that can give me the correct information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to peek the information straight from the kernel with the kernel modular debugger:

Without the hack:

```
# uname -a
SunOS s10u11 5.10 Generic_147148-26 i86pc i386 i86pc
```

With the hack:

```
# uname -a
SunOS PowerPC 5.5.1 gate:1996-12-01 PPC i386 i86pc

# echo "$<utsname" | mdb -k
{
    sysname = [ "SunOS" ]
    nodename = [ "s10u11" ]
    release = [ "5.10" ]
    version = [ "Generic_147148-26" ]
    machine = [ "i86pc" ]
}
```